# Custom JWT Generation Gives Exception in WSO2 3.2.0

Tags: jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I’m trying to add custom roles to the existing JWT token by using CustomGatewayJWTGenerator as described here:
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/
But unfortunately I’m getting a nullpointer error as shown below (wso2am-3.2.0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.generateAndRetrieveJWTToken_aroundBody2(JWTValidator.java:214) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.generateAndRetrieveJWTToken(JWTValidator.java:195) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate_aroundBody0(JWTValidator.java:181) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate(JWTValidator.java:111) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate_aroundBody4(OAuthAuthenticator.java:300) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
```

Also here is my relevant enabled attributes in the deployment.toml

```
[apim.jwt]
enable = true

[apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator"
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share whether you are using API Manager 3.2.0 GA release (or WUM updated release)? Have you applied any patches in your environment?

Comment: @Athiththan I'm using API Manager 3.2.0 GA. I just downloaded from the Internet and did not apply any patch or new update. Do you think any update will solve that problem?

Comment: The shared traces are not aligning with the [source code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.7.206/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/jwt/JWTValidator.java#L214). I was able to build the sample and invoke the APIs successfully. Could you please share the link from where you have downloaded the pack? So that I can have another round of tests. Further, can you also share an extract of the code that you are trying on the custom JWT Generator?

Comment: I cloned and build with maven clean build without touching anything from https://github.com/wso2/samples-apim . Then I put the output jar to the repository/components/lib/ and restart the WSO2 again. Then, when I call a backend service with a valid token though WSO2,  then exception is thrown. I just downloaded 3.2.0 MacOS version directly from https://wso2.com/api-management/previous-releases/.

Comment: Ohhh ... Can you remove the existing JAR from both `<apim>/repository/components/lib` and `dropins` directory and place the JAR only inside the `<apim>/repository/components/dropins` directory and try the scenario? (restart the server after making the changes)

Answer (score 0):

As per the shared information, the built JAR artifact has been placed inside the `<apim>/repository/components/lib` directory.

Perform the following steps to overcome the behavior

- Go to `<apim>/repository/components/lib` directory and remove the custom JWT Generator JAR
- Move to `<apim>/repository/components/dropins` directory and remove the custom JWT Generator bundle JAR (this is an OSGi bundle that is created during the startup for the JAR that is placed under the `/lib` directory)
- Place the built JAR artifact only inside the `<apim>/repository/components/dropins` and restart the API Manager server

After restart, try invoking the API.

Comment: I tried also your suggestion. But still having the same problem :( Thank you anyway

Comment: Are you still observing the Null Pointer Exception when invoking the API? Is it the same trace or is throwing from a different location now?

Comment: Yes unfortunately. Event I download a new fresh version of the WSO and put the new compiled jar into the <apim>/repository/components/dropins folder, still observing the nullpointer.